# Prove or disprove that $(1+\mathrm{e}s)\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-sx}}{2x\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(\ln x + 1)^2}{8}}\mathrm{d} x \ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, expected-value

$\color{blue}{\textrm{Edit: As @Claude Leibovici pointed out, the inequality is not true.}}$

> Prove or disprove that, for all $s \ge 0$,
> $$(1+\mathrm{e}s)\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-sx}\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(\ln x + 1)^2}{8}}\mathrm{d} x \ge 1.$$

**Background**. In my answer to the question [Inequality for convex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3882121/inequality-for-convex-function),
I did not prove the above inequality.

The inequality can be rephrased as follows. Let $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. Prove (or disprove) that, for all $s \ge 0$,
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathrm{e}^{-s\mathrm{e}^{2X-1}}\right] \ge \frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}s}.$$

**My attempt**.

Using $\mathrm{e}^{-u} \ge 1 - u$ for all $u \ge 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &(1+\mathrm{e}s)\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-sx}\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(\ln x + 1)^2}{8}}\mathrm{d} x\\
 \ge\,& (1+\mathrm{e}s)\int_0^{1/s} \mathrm{e}^{-sx}\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(\ln x + 1)^2}{8}}\mathrm{d} x\\
 \ge\,& (1+\mathrm{e}s)\int_0^{1/s} (1 - sx)\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(\ln x + 1)^2}{8}}\mathrm{d} x\\
 =\,& \frac{1 + \mathrm{e} s}{2}
 + \frac{1 + \mathrm{e} s}{2}\,\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\ln \frac{1}{s} + \frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\right) \\
 &\quad - \frac{\mathrm{e}s(1 + \mathrm{e}s)}{2} - \frac{\mathrm{e}s(1 + \mathrm{e}s)}{2}\,\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\ln \frac{1}{s} - \frac{3}{4}\sqrt 2\right).
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
$$
\frac{1 + \mathrm{e} s}{2}\,\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\ln \frac{1}{s} + \frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\right) - \frac{\mathrm{e}s(1 + \mathrm{e}s)}{2}\,\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\ln \frac{1}{s} - \frac{3}{4}\sqrt 2\right) \ge \frac{1 + \mathrm{e}^2 s^2}{2}.$$

It is still complicated.

Comment: I personally would try and see if I could use any of the laplace transform theorems as my initial way of attacking it.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks for comment. The inequality is not true. So just ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not a proof*

Your last expression can write
$$(1+e s) \left(e s\,\text{erf}\left(\frac{\log (s)+3}{2
   \sqrt{2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{\log (s)-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)-(1+e^2s^2) \geq 0$$ If I did not so any mistake, this is true for $s <1806.26$.

Similarly, the lhs of the expression in title is smaller that $1$ as soon as $s>11083$ (by nmerical integration, for sure).

**Edit**

Even if it does not matter much, I think that there is a mistake in the last integral
$$I=(1+es)\int_0^{1/s} (1 - sx)\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(\ln x + 1)^2}{8}}\,d x$$ should be
$$I=\frac 12(1+es)\left((1-es)-e s \,\text{erf}\left(\frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{s}\right)-3}{2
   \sqrt{2}}\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{s}\right)+1}{2
   \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Thanks. I check your $I$ which is the same as my result. I used Maple.

Comment: @RiverLi. I think taht this would make the rhs of the inequaliry  $\frac{-1 + \mathrm{e}^2 s^2}{2}$

Comment: First of all, do you verify (agree) that $$\frac 12(1+es)\left((1-es)-e s \,\text{erf}\left(\frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{s}\right)-3}{2
   \sqrt{2}}\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{s}\right)+1}{2
   \sqrt{2}}\right)\right) = $$ $$\frac{1 + \mathrm{e} s}{2}
 + \frac{1 + \mathrm{e} s}{2}\,\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\ln \frac{1}{s} + \frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\right) - \frac{\mathrm{e}s(1 + \mathrm{e}s)}{2} - \frac{\mathrm{e}s(1 + \mathrm{e}s)}{2}\,\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\ln \frac{1}{s} - \frac{3}{4}\sqrt 2\right)$$

Comment: I checked. My attempt is not true. Also, the inequality in the title is not true. Thanks. (+1)